# How can display text only when mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgxGqR)

**CODE HTML:**

SED PERSPICIATIS

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit
                    voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
                    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
                    veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt
                    explicabo.

```
<div class="col-md-4 tab-bottom">
    <div class="tab-bottom-img"><img width="380" height="380" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1-380x380.png" class="attachment-news wp-post-image" alt="1"> </div>
    <div class="tab-bottom-content">
        <div>
            <p class="title_bottom">SED PERSPICIATIS</p>
            <p class="content_bottom"></p><p>
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit<br>
                voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,<br>
                totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore<br>
                veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt<br>
                explicabo.
            </p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 tab-bottom">
    <div class="tab-bottom-img"><img width="380" height="380" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1-380x380.png" class="attachment-news wp-post-image" alt="1"> </div>
    <div class="tab-bottom-content">
        <div>
            <p class="title_bottom">SED PERSPICIATIS</p>
            <p class="content_bottom"></p><p>
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit<br>
                voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,<br>
                totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore<br>
                veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt<br>
                explicabo.
            </p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
.tab-bottom {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    float:left;
}
.tab-bottom-img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.tab-bottom-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$(".tab-bottom").bind('mouseover',function(event){
    $(this).find("tab-bottom-content").css("display", "block");
});
$('.tab-bottom-img').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {

});
```

I want the text in the div `tab-bottom-content` to be displayed only when the mouse is over.

I tried to use the script above but unfortunately does not work

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code pen is empty.

Comment: sorry, it is now well

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using CSS instead.

like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f96u90t/1/)

Example html:

```
<div class=tab-bottom>
  <div class=tab-bottom-content>
     Test
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-bottom{
  border: 1px SOLID #F00; /* For display purpose */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.tab-bottom.tab-bottom-content{
  display: none;
}
.tab-bottom:hover .tab-bottom-content{
  display: block;
}
```

There is no need for JavaScript or jQuery here :)

Answer (score 1):

You should initially hide `.tab-bottom-content` using `display: none` like following.

```
.tab-bottom-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none
}
```

And the use following jQuery. You missed the `.` before `tab-bottom-content`

```
$(".tab-bottom").mouseover(function(event){
    $(this).find(".tab-bottom-content").show(300);
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).find(".tab-bottom-content").hide(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need '.' in this **.find("tab-bottom-content")**

```
$(".tab-bottom").on('mouseover',function(event){
    $(this).find(".tab-bottom-content").show(300);
});
$('.tab-bottom').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).find(".tab-bottom-content").hide(300);
});
```

[Here is the pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZyVLo)

You must also add CSS

```
.tab-bottom-content {
    display:none;
 }
```

or inline style to hide the 'tab-bottom-content' content first

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity of the `tab-bottom-content` to `0` and then change it to `1` in its `:hover` pseudo-selector class so that the text appears when you hover over the `tab-bottom-content` div. You may even want to add a `transition` so that the opacity changes smoothly. Do this,

```
.tab-bottom-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
}

.tab-bottom-content:hover {
  opacity: 1
}
```

Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/5s1fv2a9/